# ABS bed adhesion on a textured glass bed (AnyCubic Chiron)?

Tags: adhesion, abs, glass-bed

I have printed a lot of ABS in the past and understand the issues of shrinkage and adhesion. My previous printer had smooth window glass surface, and both clean surface and hairspray would usually do the trick.

My new AnyCubic Chiron has a textured surface and heat bed, which has so far worked great for PLA. For ABS however it de-laminates before the print is even 5mm tall. Tried the print with a clean surface and with a hairspray coated surface; the part quickly de-laminates. Any one with experience using these textured surfaces for ABS?

Don't really want to go the ABS juice route if possible. Just debating if I should cover/replace this fancy new textured glass with old-school smooth window glass.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The (basically) BEST way to optimise bed adhesion is to follow the instructions from https://magigoo.com/blog/3d-printing-perfect-first-layer-magigoo/

The summary is: print the wedge they provide at different bed temperatures (keep the filament constant) and see which one adheres the best. You will build a table like

[image]

then you can see what works best.

I did it with nylon and it improved things a lot. Since I use bed levelling, I printed the wedges on different spots of the bed because it was faster (print the coldest, remove and heat the bed further, and so on), but another option is to remove the wedge, clean the bed, reapply spray, and proceed.

I haven't printed much ABS since I got my current printer, but when I did I can tell you that Dimafix worked very well, holding the print flat when hot (90+ °C) and releasing it by itself below 40 °C. It needs to be reapplied each time, contrary to hairspray (which I usually use, it also works).